# markdown code block indent doesn't work

Tags: markdown

When I try to write below markdown, I know I need to indent the code block with 4 space, then the item index number will be correct.

But actually code block can not be indent by space, otherwise it will not displayed as a code block.

See below example:

````
1. line 1

```
-    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Allow utf-8 characters in the tex document
    ```

2. line 2

    ```
-    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Allow utf-8 characters in the tex document
    ```
````

Now the output is:

[image]

You can see the first item is fine, but the 2nd item doesn't. The only difference is the 2nd one has 4 space indent.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Modified question for better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown can't tell if you want to start a new list or resume an existing one if you have non-list items between the numbered list items.  But you can specify a starting value with each list item:

````
1. line 1

```
code block1
```
2. line 2

```
code block2
```
3. line 3

```
code block3
```
````

Comment: it seems code content depended, see my example http://stackoverflow.com/a/28651646/1914781